# using the Downward API to access multiple container name kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

Is there a programmatic way to get the container name in the pod `spec`?

I have multiple app containers running in a single POD via `Deployment.yaml`.

My `fluentd` instance is running as a sidecar in the deployment. Fluentd needs to collect the logs emitted from these containers. How does it identify a container's name?

The downward API looks promising in this regard. However, the container name is not mentioned in the Capabilities of the Downward API section.

Any workaround solution?

```yaml
  - name: fluentd
    image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-forward
    env:
      - name:  FLUENT_FOWARD_HOST
        value: "10.10.132.59"
      - name:  FLUENT_FOWARD_PORT
        value: "24224"
      - name: K8S_NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      - name: K8S_POD
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
```